# Is it possible to update only build number on app store?

Tags: ios, app-store, version, build-numbers

When I update only the build number of an app for Testflight users, they get the update immediately without waiting for approval. Is the same thing possible for App Store updates? Is there a faster way than creating a new version and waiting for approval each time I have an update?

The approval for new versions is taking too long in my case, mostly 2 days. Could this be because the app requires sign-in?

Answer (score 4):

All updates have to go through the approval process before being released on the App Store. Welcome to iOS development.